# Authentication in Java using Spring LDAP

Tags: java, spring-security, ldap, spring-boot

I'm trying to connect to an AD from Spring LDAP Project

I don't find any method from the `DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource` to set the CN for Authentication.

```
public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource context = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource("ldaps://test.ldaps.com/DC=test,DC=ldaps,DC=com");
        context.setPassword("password");
        context.afterPropertiesSet();
        auth
                .ldapAuthentication()
                .userSearchFilter("(|(objectClass=person)(objectClass=user))")
                .userDnPatterns("uid={0},OU=people)")
                .contextSource(context);
}
```

I didn't found a method like `contect.setUserCN()`.

Comment: have you try with `LdapTemplate` ?

Comment: no only with spring ldap project https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/

Comment: i dont want to use any xml file for settings

Answer (score 3):

There should not be a need to set a CN. You just have to specify a managerDN and managerPass as below in context. Security Ldap will then use the context to look for a user which is matching then criteria, retrieving its DN and afterwards trying to issue a bind with the retrieved DN and the given pass.

This is our configuration which is working fine:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private SecurityConfigProperties conf;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authBuilder) throws Exception {
        authBuilder
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})")
            .userSearchBase("dc=XXXX,dc=XXXXXX,dc=XXX")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=XXXXXXX,dc=XXXX,dc=XXXXXX,dc=XXX")
            .groupSearchFilter("member={0}")
            .contextSource()
                .url(conf.getLdapUrl())
                .port(conf.getLdapPort())
                .managerDn(conf.getBindCn()) 
                .managerPassword(conf.getBindPass());
    }

}
```

But following your code example `context.setUserDN()` should be what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for your answer! 
but whats the import for SecurityConfigProperties? or in wich spring package i find it?

Comment: It's just a class we created to automatically catch some properties from the config file using `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "ldap") public class SecurityConfigProperties`

Comment: Perfect! Would be great if you accept this answer as solution.

Comment: could you maybe explain wath the parameters (sAMAccountName={0}) and member={0} do?

Comment: `sAMAccountName` is the LDAP parameter carrying the old pre-AD username without the domain prefix. Just guessing why Microsoft couldn't go the standard LDAP way and use `uid`. `member` is the parameter which is used to look for groups where the user is a member in. In fact there will just be a search being executed with `member=<usersDN>` to resolve all group memberships.

Comment: ah ok. thanks for that, but why they are 0? in the microsoft reference is the definition of samAccountName that its a 20 length character? thats confusing me why im setting it to 0.

Comment: `{0}` is the placeholder for the first param passed which is the username. And the same is valid for `member`.